# Web Api route returns a 404

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2012

Given the uri...

```
http://localhost:5613/api/user/1/HasCompletedInitialScreen
```

I have the following route configured...

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiUserHasCompletedInitialScreen",
            routeTemplate: "api/user/{id}/{hascompletedinitialscreen}");

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

and the controller action...

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("HasCompletedInitialScreen")]
public HttpResponseMessage HasCompletedInitialScreen(int id)
{
    var response = Request.CreateResponse<bool>(HttpStatusCode.Created, true);
    response.Headers.Location = GetLocation(id);
    return response;
}
```

However, I get a 404.  How do I fix my route configuration and/or controller action to make this work?

Many thanks!!

**UPDATE**

Based on the accepted answer, I modified my api route definition to the following.  Hope this helps someone else...

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "QueryApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do but, if you want to be able to call

```
http://localhost:5613/api/user/1/HasCompletedInitialScreen
```

Your route needs to be like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ApiUserHasCompletedInitialScreen",
                routeTemplate: "api/user/{id}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Something" }
            );
```

Where `SomethingController` is your controller containing the `HasCompletedInitialScreen` action.

On a side note, you don't need to declare `ActionName` attribute if its name is the same as your action method name.